# Scroll to y location within react element with useRef

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I have an component on my page that scrolls, but the rest doesn't. I want to scroll to a certain Y location within this element, when I change a useState value using a different component.

```
const scrollMe = useRef();  

useEffect(
        () => {
                if (scrollMe === true) {
                    scrollPanel.scrollTo(0, 300)
                }

        },
        [ scrollMe ]
    );
```

The scrollable component is like so:

```
 <div ref={scrollMe} onScroll={(e) => handleScroll(e)}>A mapped array</div>
```

The scroll function is as follows:

```
const handleScroll = (e) => {
    if (e.target.scrollTop !== 0) {
        setTopBarPosition(true);
    } else {
        setTopBarPosition(false);
    }
};
```

Setting the topBarPosition affects

```
<div className={`topBar ${topBarPosition === true ? 'topBarToTop' : ''}`}>
                    <TopBar/>
</div>
```

And the css class topBarToTop moves the topBar to the top of the page:

```
.topBarToTop {
    top: 30px;
}
```

How come I just get scrollMe.scrollTo is not a function ?

I made a codesandbox that illustrates what I'm trying to do:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-izho9

Comment: Can you please post the whole component or at least where you use `scrollMe` reference?

Comment: Please, create a codesandbox example .It is easier to reproduce your mistake

Comment: Hi I made one - link in the question

Comment: @Davtho1983 Hey, Please take a loot at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-qeynl) Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: That is awesome thankyou! If you post that as the answer will accept :)

Comment: What about the general case where I want to scroll to y=value ?

Comment: Oh I see const newY = y + 100;
      childRef.current.scrollTo(0, newY);

Comment: @Davtho1983 Thank you. I'm glad that a could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make some small changes, Please follow the code **comments**:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // swap the conditions to check for childRef first
    if (childRef && topPosition) {

      // use to get the size (width, height) of an element and its position
      // (x, y, top, left, right, bottom) relative to the viewport.
      const { y } = childRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()

      // You have to call `current` from the Ref
      // Add the `scrollTo()` second parameter (which is left)
      childRef.current.scrollTo(y, 0)

      // Initially it was set to `false` and we change it to `true` when click on scroll
      // button then we change it back to `false` when re-render 
      setTopPosition(false)

    }
  }, [topPosition, childRef])
```

More about [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect#Examples)